# Creating RDS in ansible

Tags: ansible, amazon-rds

I am trying to learn ansible for work. I need to create RDS instance followed by a database and get env variables.

i keep getting error

fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "unsupported parameter for module: register"}

here is my code

```
- name: Configure RDS
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: Provision RDS
      rds:
        command: create
        instance_name: ANSIBLEDataloading
        db_engine: Postgresql
        size: 10
        instance_type: sb.m1.small
        username: xxxxx
        password: xxxxx
        tags:
          Environment: Dataloading
          Application: sims
        command: facts
        instance_name: ANSIBLEDataloading
        register: ANSIBLEDataloading
    - name: Add new instance to host group
      add_host: hostname={{ item.endpoint }} groupname=launched_db
      with_items: '{{ANSIBLEDataloading.instance}}'
```

I am trying to learn, very very new to ansible.

new code

```
- name: Configure RDS
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: Provision RDS
      rds:
        command: create
        instance_name: ANSIBLEDataloading
        db_engine: postgres
        region: 'us-east-1'
        size: 10
        instance_type: db.m3.xlarge
        username: xxxxx
        password: xxxx
        tags:
          Environment: Dataloading
          Application: sims
      register: ANSIBLEDataloading
    - name: Add new instance to host group
      add_host: hostname={{ item.endpoint }} groupname=launched_db
      with_items: '{{ANSIBLEDataloading.instance}}'
```

new error

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined. The error was: 'unicode object' has no attribute 'endpoint'\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/Users/suyesh/Desktop/ansible_conversion/conversion.yml': line 48, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n      register: ANSIBLEDataloading\n    - name: Add new instance to host group\n      ^ here\n"}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is simply a formatting error. register should be on the same indentation as the task.

```
  tasks:
    - name: Provision RDS
      rds:
        command: create
        instance_name: ANSIBLEDataloading
        db_engine: Postgresql
        size: 10
        instance_type: sb.m1.small
        username: xxxxx
        password: xxxxx
        tags:
          Environment: Dataloading
          Application: sims
        command: facts
        instance_name: ANSIBLEDataloading
      register: ANSIBLEDataloading
```

Comment: i am getting this error now, i will update above. fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined. The error was: 'unicode object' has no attribute 'endpoint'\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/Users/suyesh/Desktop/ansible_conversion/conversion.yml': line 48, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n      register: ANSIBLEDataloading\n    - name: Add new instance to host group\n      ^ here\n"}

Comment: Where are you defining the variable "endpoint"? Are you providing your entire playbook file? The error message is indicating that you have not defined "endpoint" as a variable and I don't see where you have/have not in the code you provided.

Comment: Thats my entire playbook.

Comment: I want to create rds and then create a dabase in there and get the credentials for it

Comment: Then your current problem is that you are calling a variable (endpoint) that you have not defined.